# Does a collection initialize set the initial size of a HashSet properly?

Tags: c#, memory, collections

Does a collection initialization also set the resulting set's initial size?

Specifically: Is this code...

```
var someSet = new HashSet<int> { 42, 667 };
```

...equivalent to the code below, where the initial size is set explicitly?

```
var someSet = new HashSet<int>(2) { 42, 667 };
```

Comment: This is pretty opinion-based. Providing the initial capacity of course saves you some nano-seconds in case you know it.

Comment: You don't set it's size but it's initial capacity. The way a lot of these "dynamic" (meaning you can add/remove elements) datastructures work is that they have a fixed underlying datastructure (usually an array) that supports until a certain capacity. If it's at maximum capacity and you add another element it'll then rebuild it's own internal datastructure to support more elements, this is a relative expensive operation. So if you know and set the initial capacity you can skip this internal rebuilding while adding the initial elements.

Comment: However that won´t hinder anyone on adding more elements to the underlying array - even above the initial size.

Comment: @HimBromBeere It's not opinion-based, just a matter of having access to the relevant source code

Comment: There's some interesting code in the `HashSet` implementation. For example, if you have more than 7,199,369 elements then when it next expands the underlying array, it will search for the next higher prime! See [the ref source for HashSet](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System.Runtime.Serialization/System/Runtime/Serialization/ObjectToIdCache.cs#L175)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR;** Don't use a collection initializer, if you have a pre-existing array or collection.

The collection initializer just uses `Add()` to create the collection, so yes, it is slightly better for performance to set the size first. It's unlikely you will actually notice any difference in most cases though.

---

The code for [the relevant HashSet constructor](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.core/R/d0822f25708256c5.html) has this little gem:

```cs
        public HashSet(IEnumerable<T> collection, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
        {
...........
               // to avoid excess resizes, first set size based on collection's count. Collection
                // may contain duplicates, so call TrimExcess if resulting hashset is larger than
                // threshold
                ICollection<T> coll = collection as ICollection<T>;
                int suggestedCapacity = coll == null ? 0 : coll.Count;
                Initialize(suggestedCapacity);
 
                this.UnionWith(collection);
```

So if you have an existing array (which is an `ICollection<T>`, as is a `List<T>`) then it won't matter. It's only an issue when using LINQ `Where` etc, or when using collection initializers.

Comment: Note that while correct in general this answer is not related to the question. There are no collections in collections initializer...

Comment: True, I was trying to say: if you are worried about perf, then presize. Will reword